# app engine urls don't match

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I am trying to match every URL made of digits.

My YAML file:

```
- url: /createaccount/(^\d+$)
script: Python/CreateAccount.py
```

And the Python file:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/createaccount', CreateAccount),
                                  ('/createaccount/(^/d+$)', Confirmation)
                                  ], debug = True)
```

But it doesn't match URLs like `/createaccount/123`, how come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
(^/d+$)
```

to

```
(\d+)$
```

I'm sure of what `^` does when matching isn't in MULTILINE mode, but it almost certainly isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd even remove the $ sign:

```
- url: /createaccount/\d+
script: Python/CreateAccount.py


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/createaccount', CreateAccount),
                                  ('/createaccount/(\d+)', Confirmation)
                                  ], debug = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

reverse the 2 declarations.
put the more specific one first:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/createaccount/(\d+)', Confirmation),
                                      ('/createaccount', CreateAccount)
                                      ], debug = True)
```

that should be it.